# MVC URL pointing to the wrong Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i am very new to mvc

> //localhost:51525/api/products/GetPromotionTypes

the controller i have got is as bellow

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return Utility.GetDiscountItems();
    }

    public Product GetProduct(string Id)
    {
        return Utility.GetProduct(Id);
    }
    public String PostBag(Bag bagofItem)
    {
        return Utility.PostBagDiscountedItem(bagofItem);
    }
    public List<PromotionType> GetPromotionTypes()
     {
         return Utility.GetPromotionTypes();
     }
```

when i call from the above uri it pointing to the controller GetProduc() but what i wanted it to call GetPromotionTypes()

what i have done wrong 
appreciate all your help

Comment: This a WebAPIController?

Comment: what's the name of your controller, is it api, and products is an "action" ?
just show us your controller code, and you routes, we'll be able to help you better

Answer (score 2):

If this is a WebAPI Controller, then you can only have one GET method per controller.

WebAPI was designed to only have 5 calls, GET (one item / list items), POST, PUT and DELETE per entity type. This allows for REST URLs, such as Folders/Get/5, Folders/Get etc.

You should add another API Controller for `PromotionType`.

Have a run through this tutorial here. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Yep I'm pretty sure it is indeed WebAPI (`/api/products/`) good catch.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Thanks! :) Yeah noticed the `/api/` in the url.

Comment: Specifically, I'd point to [Routing and Action Selection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection). I'd also note that you can have multiple GET actions, but with different parameters - so you can have more than 5.

Comment: @Kobi Yeah multiple GET actions but only for one entity type.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `Routing` set up properly. I suppose it treats your call as an simple `GET` request with `GetPromotionTypes` parameter.